# Error packaging and signing BlackBerry WebWorks SDK application for Playbook

Tags: blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

I've been trying to follow the BlackBerry docs on signing a WebWorks SDK application on the command line and uploading to App World.

Here is a [chart showing the high level picture](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23959/Signing_your_application_1422721_11.jsp), and here are [the detailed instructions](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23959/Configure_app_signing_from_cmd_line_1463563_11.jsp#Sign_your_app_from_cmd_line_1463564_11) I am trying to follow.

I ran the first few steps successfully:

> ```
> C:\MyDir>blackberry-signer -csksetup -cskpass <mypwd>
> CSK file created.
>
> C:\MyDir>blackberry-signer -register -csjpin <mypin> -cskpass <mypwd> client-RDK-<snip>.csj
> Successfully registered with server.
>
> C:\MyDir>blackberry-keytool -genkeypair -keystore sigtool.p12 -storepass <mypwd> -dname "cn=<My Company>" -alias author
> <No output!>
> ```

The instructions now say I need to package my BAR file.  It links to [another web page](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23959/Package_your_application_cmd_line_1491096_11.jsp) that says to run a command like this:

```
blackberry-airpackager -package output_filename project_name-app.xml project_name.swf any_other_project_files
```

Although that sounds like it applies to an AIR application instead of a WebWorks SDK one I try it anyway, and I get an error:

> ```
> C:\MyDir>blackberry-airpackager -package output\MyApp.bar config.xml input
> C:\MyDir\config.xml: error 102: Invalid namespace http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets
> Error: AIR validation failed
> ```

I then see if either of the `blackberry-packager` or `blackberry-nativepackager` commands is the right one.  Running `blackberry-nativepackager` yields this error `Error: not qnx tag or two many`, and the usage of `blackberry-packager` seems to be inappropriate, e.g.

```
Usage:
  blackberry-packager -generatemanifest [<manifest-file>]
  blackberry-packager -verifymanifest <manifest-file>
  blackberry-packager -metafolder <META-INF folder> [-javafolder <java-folder>] [-datafolder <data-folder>] [-nativefolder <native-folder>] [-airfolder <air-folder>] [-nocompression] <barfile.bar> (<inputfile>)*
```

So, I now revert back to packaging as I originally did during my testing, i.e. I create a ZIP file and use `bbwp.exe`:

> ```
> C:\MyDir>bbwp.exe "MyApp.zip" -o "output"
> [INFO]                  Parsing command line options
> <snip>
> [INFO]                  Packaging the bar file
> [INFO]                  Bar packaging complete
> [INFO]                  WebWorks application packaging complete
> ```

That looks good so I move onto the final two steps, which are:

```
blackberry-signer -verbose -cskpass <mypwd> -keystore sigtool.p12 -storepass <mypwd> output\MyApp.bar RDK
blackberry-signer -keystore sigtool.p12 -storepass <mypwd> output\MyApp.bar author
```

Unfortunately the first of these steps fails:

> ```
> C:\MyDir>blackberry-signer -verbose -cskpass <mypwd> -keystore sigtool.p12 -storepass <mypwd> output\MyApp.bar RDK
> <snip>
> 42 43 65 30 58 31 19 36 79 22 50 64 71 12 38 4e
> 74 68 78 34
> Connecting to url http://www.rim.net/Websigner/servlet/RDK-Waterloo
> Sending properties to server...
> Properties of response := [
> Version = 1
> Response = Signature Response
> Confirm = null
> Error = Code signing request failed because Application-Development-Mode in Manifest is present and is not set to [false].
> ]
> barsigner error: server error: Code signing request failed because Application-Development-Mode in Manifest is present and is not set to [false].
> ```

That exact error is documented [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23959/Configure_app_signing_from_cmd_line_1463563_11.jsp), along with this explanation of it:

> Code signing request failed because Application-Development-Mode in Manifest is present and is not set to false
>   **Description**
>   This message appears when you try to sign a .bar file that
>   was packaged in Development mode.
>   **Possible solution**
>   Repackage the .bar file. If you use
>   blackberry-packager, or another
>   command line tool, do not include the
>   debug option in your command line.

Unfortunately that doesn't help me at all.  My understanding is that the config.xml file in the WebWorks SDK replaces the need for a MANIFEST.MF file.

Can anybody help me with this misery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, my problem appears to be that I was following the signing instructions for an AIR application, not a WebWorks SDK application.

[Here are the WebWorks SDK instructions](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23977/Configure_signing_for_tablet_applications_1476061_11.jsp) to follow, along with summary steps below.

```
blackberry-signer -csksetup -cskpass <mypwd> 
blackberry-signer -register -csjpin <mypin> -cskpass <mypwd> client-RDK-<snip>.csj    
blackberry-keytool -genkeypair -keystore sigtool.p12 -storepass <mypwd> -dname "cn=<My Company>" -alias author 
bbwp.exe "MyApp.zip" -gcsk <mypwd> -gp12 <mypwd> -o "output"
```

I had originally followed these steps successfully, and my confusion started because BlackBerry sent me an e-mail after my first submission which said:

> Also, to make your app available for
>   download, there is one additional
>   step. Each app must be “signed” and
>   resubmitted into BlackBerry App World;
>   if you haven’t signed your application
>   please review our blog post that
>   contains the needed information to
>   sign your application.  Please sign
>   your application and resubmit to
>   BlackBerry App World.  When
>   resubmitting add “_signed” to the end
>   of the bundle name and rest assured
>   you will not lose your spot in the
>   review queue.

I e-mailed them asking them to confirm if there was a problem with my signing, and I hadn't got a reply after 5 days, so I thought I may have followed the wrong instructions. :-(

FTR, this question was cross posted with the BlackBerry developer forum [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/Error-packaging-and-signing-BlackBerry-WebWorks-SDK-application/m-p/970143/highlight/false#M11239).

Answer (score 1):

You can try posting in the BlackBerry Web Development support forum, there is RIM staff monitoring that forum:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/bd-p/browser_dev

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that but I generally try to avoid the BlackBerry forum.  I had e-mailed BlackBerry about this issue on 23rd and 25th March, but as I've still not got a response I've now cross posted this question on the BlackBerry forum: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/Error-packaging-and-signing-BlackBerry-WebWorks-SDK-application/td-p/970117 I'll update both if/when I find a solution!